# How to edit table headers with VBA - Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I Have a sheet that adds a table for each project I got in a list.
But I can't find the code to edit the table headers after the table is added.
There probably is an easy solution, but I can't manage to find one.

```
Sub getAllProjectsTest()
    Dim totalSheet As Worksheet
    Set totalSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Total Overview")

    totalSheet.Range("A2:Z4000").Clear

    For Each project In Sheets("Projects-Tasks").Range("Projects")
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = totalSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        With totalSheet.Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(3, 0)
            .Value = project
            .Font.Size = 16
            .Font.Bold = True
        End With

        Dim ListStart As String
        ListStart = totalSheet.Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(4, 0).Address

        Dim TableWidth As String
        TableWidth = totalSheet.Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(4, 3).Address

        totalSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range(ListStart & ":" & TableWidth), , xlYes).Name = "Table" & project
        Range(ListStart & ":" & TableWidth).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

    Next project
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It becomes easier if you work with objects. See this example

```
'
'~~> Rest of the code
'
Dim tbl As ListObject

Set tbl = totalSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, _
          Range(ListStart & ":" & TableWidth), , xlYes)

With tbl
    .Name = "Table" & project
    Debug.Print .HeaderRowRange.Address
End With
'
'~~> Rest of the code
'
```

Comment: Thanks that does make it better indeed, but how do i edit the table headers from that HeaderRowRange?

Comment: You  mean `tbl.HeaderRowRange.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Blah Blah"`?

Comment: Yes thank you! That should work. had a little brainfart on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Another more fun way to do this.

```
Sub trimHeaders()

Dim wlistobj As ListObject
Dim wlistcol As ListColumn
Set wlistobj = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).ListObjects(1)


For Each wlistcol In wlistobj.ListColumns
    wlistobj.HeaderRowRange.Cells(wlistcol.DataBodyRange.Column) = Trim(wlistobj.HeaderRowRange.Cells(wlistcol.DataBodyRange.Column))
Next wlistcol

End Sub
```